# reshaping a 1d numpy array to 2d

Tags: python, numpy

The following is the code i'm trying to run:

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.zeros(1400*2100, dtype=np.uint8)
np.reshape(mask,(1400,2100), order='F')
print(mask.shape)
```

The output comes out to be:
`(2940000,)`

i'm expecting `mask` to reshape to `(1400,2100)` .
what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`np.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) operation does not modify the `mask` reference at all, but rather produces a new array. If you want to use the same name for the input and the result, you could let

```
mask = np.reshape(mask, (1400, 2100), order='F')
```

or, the slightly shorter

```
mask = mask.reshape((1400, 2100), order='F')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to reassign the output of `np.reshape(mask,(1400,2100), order='F')` to variable `mask`:

```
mask=np.reshape(mask,(1400,2100), order='F')
```